# How to flip values in columns into column headers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
    Id   field          value
0   1    first_name      a
1   1    number          123
2   1    last_name       aa
0   2    first_name      b
1   2    number          456
2   2    last_name       bb
3   2    type            p
```

Each Id has a different length of index and roughly the same field types but some have more some have less.

How do I flip the df so that fields are columns and values are underneath them?

Like so:

```
    Id   first_name   number   last_name    type
0   1      a          123         aa    
1   2      b          456         bb         p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also just `.pivot`

```
df.pivot(index='Id', columns='field', values='value').reset_index()
#field  Id first_name last_name number type
#0       1          a        aa    123  NaN
#1       2          b        bb    456    p
```

If you get ValueError, this likely means that you have a row duplicated on `['Id', 'field']`. This will make it work, but will chose the value as whichever row appears first in your `DataFrame`.

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='Id', columns='field', values='value', aggfunc='first')
```

Comment: Your second answer works, How can I make the index a ordered set of numbers instead of the `ID`? 

The `ID` needs to be used else where

Comment: I reset the index with `reset_index`

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
out = df.set_index(['Id', 'field']).unstack()
out.columns = out.columns.get_level_values(1)
out.reset_index()
```

```
field  Id first_name last_name number type
0       1          a        aa    123  NaN
1       2          b        bb    456    p
```

Comment: I get error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`. I know this is because the index repeats for every different ID.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't get that issue.  Maybe try `reset_index` first?

Comment: after resetting the index the error I get is ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape